# Как исправить проблему соединения интернета в Ubuntu-Mate?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, модемы, mate

У меня есть ZTE модем и когда я подключаюсь к интернету в Ubuntu-Mate, интернет появляеться но после некоторое время интернет сразу снижается и после переставки модема ничего не получаеться если после перезагрузки то никак.

В Windows нет таких проблем, интернет работает на максимальной скорости.

Посоветуйте что нибудь (Я пробовал изменить конфигурацию по совету в Askubuntu) !

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса хотя бы модель модема и версию прошивки, провайдера, уточните что такое "интернет снижается" и "переставка модема" и "после перезагрузки никак" ..

Comment: ZTE mf-180 модема и я прошил и изменил программу модема на Коннект менеджера, провайдер Мегафон и интернет снижается - это в первую 3 минуты интернет работает нормально но потом интернет работает плохо открываю страницу и после минуты 2 откроется а это проблема продолжается до тех пор пока я сделаю перезагрузку компьютера и потом тоже так циклично появляется это проблема! Мой вопрос такой: Как сделать так чтобы модем работал быстрее и использовалось весь трафик а не минимум трафика !                        @Kromster А за исправление спасибо но я не русский !

Comment: Внесите правку в вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: я что что-та непонятное написал что ли ?

Comment: я вам помогаю оформить вопрос, чтобы он был яснее и на него было проще дать ответ. Не хотите помощи - дело ваше

Comment: Если бы я не хотел помощи я бы сюда не пришёл мой дорогой друг @Kromster ! Скажите где здесь непонятно написано ? Я же в комментариях детально сказал !

Comment: Непонятно написано в вопросе. Отвечающих всегда меньше, чем спрашивающих и вам рекомендуют простой способ увеличения шансов на то, чтобы получить ответ: перенести уточнения из комментариев в сам вопрос. Иногда авторы ленятся и у них под вопросом десятки комментариев с уточнениями -- отсюда и типовая рекомендация: Вопросы с просьбами помочь должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения ***прямо в вопросе***.

Comment: А у меня дело обратное, есть мак в нем win 10 на дуал-буте так вот win 10 интернет ловит ужасно.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

после строчки hosts:

```
files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
```

вставить hosts:

files dns